# gensync error after updating from Nexj.Js 12 to Next.Js 13

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, next.js13

I wrote some unit test cases using jest and @testing-library/react

My test cases was working fine on Next.Js 12
But when I Updated to Next.Js 13, I am facing an issue with the error message in console.

Cannot find module 'gensync'

Can anyone help me in this problem.

*Please note: My test cases was working fine on next js 12. I have an another branch with the name "main". The main branch was running on next js 13. I merged the main branch into my testing branch. And After merge I am facing the issue. I resolved the conflicts.*

I tries to delete package-lock.json and again running the command
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
npm i --save-dev

Not working

Deleted node_modules
and again installing the packages

not resolved the issue.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75182686/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).